# ¿como envio dos parametros via url? php

Tags: php, laravel

Hola estoy utilizando laravel, quisiera saber como puedo enviar dos parametros por url..

Ruta:

```
Route::get('detalle/{subcategoria}/{codigo}', [
    'as' => 'detalle',
    'uses' => 'principalController@cargarDetalle',
]);
```

Url:

```
<a href="{{ route('detalle',['subcategoria' => $articulo->subcategoria, 'codigo' => $articulo->id])}}#article"></a>
```

Me genera el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Buen Día intenta colocarlo de la siguiente manera

```
Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'subcategoria/{categoria}/{subcategoria}',['as' => 'codigo', 'uses' => 'principalController/cargarDetalle']);
```

Comment: Lo pude solucionar cambiadolo a: {{ url('producto',['subcategoria' => $articulo->descripcion, 'codigo' => $articulo->id])}}